# Is this a distance ? if not, what is it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, mathematical-physics

Explanation: I want when the order relation $(a\lt b)$ is verified that the result is positive and that if it is not respected, the result is negative, consequently if it is equal, it must be neither one nor the other, i.e. $0$.

In maths it give :

$For\ a < b \ with\ (a,b) \in Z^2 :$

axiom 1 : $ a⨭b = |a+b|;$

axiom 2 : $b⨭a = -( a⨭b) = a⨮b = - |a+b|$;

axiom 3 : $b⨮a = a⨭b$;

axiom 4 : $a⨭a = a⨮a = 0$

(think ⨭as +< and ⨮ as +> or -<)

During my research i find this: Grassmann number :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number

We can see this used in Astrophysics for Supersymmetry (La Supersymétrie; ScienceClic; https://youtu.be/fDeqvjgQ46s?si=wC7DRwl74KG-w-k3&t=356)

$$\theta_a \times \theta_b = - \theta_b  \times \theta_a $$
$$\theta_x^2 = - \theta_x^2 = 0$$

→ I think what i wrote in my question is a sort of weird distance, it don't respect triangle inequality but Travel time don't respect it too !

ex :

A shorter path that crosses a mountain and takes 600 minutes.

Vs

A detour through a town that takes 20 minutes to reach the town, then 25 minutes to reach the objective.

https://zupimages.net/up/23/51/8jsi.png

Also a distance can be negative ! :
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesure_alg%C3%A9brique (btw sorry, but weirdly not English page for Algebraic measurement)

$$\overline{AB} = AB$$ et $$\overline{BA} = -AB$$

So i will try to reformulate my structure into distance language (but i know it can't be a measure, a measure is positive and must respect the triangle inequality) :

$For\ a < b \ with\ (a,b) \in Z^2 :$

$ a⨭b = |a+b|;$ -> $d(a,b) = |a+b|$

$b⨭a = -( a⨭b) = - |a+b|$; -> $d(b,a) = - |a+b|$

$a⨭a = 0$ -> $d(a,a) = 0$

So do you think it's a distance ? If not, what it could be ?

Comment: Why are those tags used? What part of this question is related to mathematical physics or noncommutative algebra?

Comment: As well as the other issues you have identified, it seems your function can be zero between distinct points: it seems $(-2) ⨭ 2 =0$.  It is difficult to see how calling this some kind of distance works.  Nor do I see why you you have such a complicated and discontinuous example.  If you had $d(a,b)=b-a$ then you would in sense have a signed distance.

Comment: $a⨭a = 0$ is not true

Comment: I think being more specific about what you mean by a 'distance' would be helpful. You acknowledge that this does not pass the triangle inequality, so you cannot be asking if it is a metric.

Comment: Grassmann number -> astrophysics;
My structure is non-commutative;

-2 ⨭ 2 =0 yes, Firstly i just would an "ordonned operator", it's after i think about it could be a sort of a distance.

a ⨭ a = 0 is an axiom of my structure, sorry to  haven't clarified it.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions, the tag noncommutative algebra is for noncommutative rings and modules over them, your question relates to neither.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your [prior (closed) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4831785/242). This violates site policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if i want this to be more likely a distance maybe i should have define it like this :
$For\ a < b \ with\ (a,b) \in Z^2 : $

axiom 1 : $ a⨭b = |a|+|b|;$

axiom 2 : $ b⨭a = -( a⨭b) = - (|a|+|b|)$;

axiom 3 : $ a⨭a = 0$

like this $-2⨭2 = 4 $ (and not 0 like previously, that was an issue) but

and $2⨭-2 = -4$

Like this is more similar to algebraic measurement i show in my question.